# How can i get url parameters in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, get, request

I have tried a lot of things but nothing is working. It always gives me the "Incomplete response received from application" message in the navigator.

My code is:

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def application():

    uri = request.args.get('url')

    message = 'It works!\n'
    response = '\n'.join([message,  uri])

    return response
```

The problem is or in the `@app.route('/')` line or in the `uri = request.args.get('url')`.

I just want to call the with the navigator like http://example.com/script/?url=hello.

I tried changing `@app.route('/')` to `@app.route('/script')` and `@app.route('/script/')` but nothing is working... any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you have two required arguments in your function and why are you returning a list?

Comment: Hi, it's only for test, but there is no need you are right

Answer (score 0):

***For future readers: note that the original question has been edited in response to this suggestion.***

First issue: You seem to be using some very low-level WSGI implementation when Flask does a lot of the sugar for you. Consider testing with a function that lets Flask do the work and then expand as needed.

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():

    uri = request.args.get('url')

    message = 'It works!\n'
    version = 'Python %s\n' % sys.version.split()[0]
    response = '\n'.join([message, version, uri])

    return response
```

Next, keep in mind that Flask wants a string return type. If you want to pass a data structure back, consider jsonify.

Comment: I tried the following and have the same issue:

`import sys
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def application():

    uri = request.args.get('url')

    message = 'It works!\n'
    response = '\n'.join([message,  uri])

    return response`

Comment: This suggests a configuration error with your webserver, based on SO questions related to the error. Will need more information about your setup there. Additionally, are you using Postman to consume this API or pulling information from a frontend of some kind?

Comment: I want to use PHP curl to do the call to the URL with the python application, but for now is fine for me to do the call only typing the URL in my navigator with the get parameters like "http://example.com/script/?url=hello.". Te URL of python application is running ok, I tested with a simple code, but when I tried to call it with get parameters and catch them in the python scripts like in the previous code, is when I have the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I would wager that Flask is throwing an error which you are unable to see. Before running the server, ```export FLASK_ENV=development``` (for mac/linux, use ```set``` for Windows) and see if that exposes the error to you.

Comment: This is mi error log:

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed App Consult the documentation on testing for information about how to avoid this problem.